# How to handle back and forward buttons in the hildon.Seekbar?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, maemo, seekbar

The [hildon.Seekbar](http://maemo.org/development/documentation/apis/3-x/python-maemo-3.x/pyhildon_seekbar/) widget consists of a scale widget and two buttons. What signals does the widget send when the buttons are clicked or how could I find out? Is there a way to monitor **all** signals/events that a widget sends in PyGTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to shows this:

```
seekbar.connect("value-changed", control_changed, label)
seekbar.connect("notify::fraction", fraction_changed, label)
```

So it seems it has (at least) two signals called "value-changed" and "notify::fraction". It also shows an inheritance diagram that tells you that the Seekbar inherits the standard GTK+ [Scale](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkScale.html) widget, which is where the first signal comes from (by further inheritance).

Not sure where the "notify::fraction" signal comes from, though.

Comment: Not sure about the differences between the two signals but in any case it seems that these signals are triggered when clicking the buttons. I misunderstood the meaning of the buttons to be "next"/"previous" song buttons but instead they're just seek buttons for the bar.

Answer (score 0):

gobjects have a way of notifying about property changes and it does this with signals. So connecting to notify::property gets you changes to property.